# With probability $o(1)$

Tags: probability, asymptotics

I am not sure how to read little/big O expressions in probability theory:

What does a statement like "with probability $1-o(1)$" mean?
Does it mean with high probability?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation

Answer (score 12):

It means that the probability tends to 1 if something goes to a limit (usually the size of the sample/object goes to infinity). Without some more context nothing more can be said.